# Sharp operator doesn't tab automatically in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

If I am writing some code in Visual Studio,

```
while(true)
{
    if (foo == bar)
       MessageBox.Show("ASDF");
}
```

And I want the code to only display the messagebox when the application is running in Debug mode, I would write #if DEBUG, #endif. But Visual studio doesn't automatically tab the # operator so it is written like this:

```
while(true)
{
    if (foo == bar)
#if DEBUG
    MessageBox.Show("ASDF");
#endif
}
```

Having to manually indent any lines that has # is annoying. How do I make visual studio to automatically tab # operators? I am using VS2010

Comment: why you want to show message box in debug mode ?

Comment: The above example is an entirely hypothetical code that is absolutely good for nothing. Please focus on the indentation part.. it's purely an issue related to the IDE

Comment: I hope this is merely a result of coming up with a simplified example, but in the `!DEBUG` case, you have invalid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no built-in way to adjust this tabbing.

Note: please consider conditional attribute on methods instead as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

```
public class Trace 
{ 
  [Conditional("DEBUG")] 
  public static void Message(string traceMessage) 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("[TRACE] - " + traceMessage); 
  } 
}
```